# Batch File Write to Temp Folder then Delete

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I'm teaching myself to write a batch file that will write a .REG file based off user's input.  Our domain computers have corporate gp's that force a lock screen, but I want a kiosk that will automatically log a user on and will not go to sleep or display a lock screen.

I know the .REG keys to add/modify, but I would like to run a .BAT file that will ask for the domain, user, and password, write that to a temp file and then use REGEDIT to run that file.  I then would like to remove that temp file after it is successfully passed through.

Should I use a user's temp folder in their profile or use the temp folder on C:\?  And will they auto delete at some point?  Or do I need to remove the file after it completes manually?

My research says no, not until a disk cleanup is ran for the second question, but verification would be appreciated, or any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

***I'm well aware of the consequences of modifying the registry.  I have backups of my test environment.***

Comment: Why you want to make a file? You can edit registry directly from your batch script

Comment: Well I'm new to writing batch files, so I thought it would be best to write the REG file to make sure it's been written correctly first, then execute.

Comment: take a look at this...[http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php)

Comment: I appreciate the link, and have been there while researching.  The uniqueid.bat file is actually what has brought me to write this question.  Starting at line 20 when they write to a temp folder in the user's profile, and thus begins my question.  Or are you referring to when he explicitly uses DEL?

Comment: Nope, i was pointing to the Self-contained registry scripts section

Comment: Not sure what "line 20" you are refering to.  As Dusan said, you can do this without a temp file.  See REG /? for help with registry operations (not avail on Windows 200 and prior).  When you say "to make sure it's been written correctly first, then execute"... I'm not sure if you mean while you are developing your script or each time it executes.  If you mean while developing, then do "ECHO.REG ADD ...whatever" (without the quotes).  This will allow you to see what you would execute.  Remove the ECHO. when you have it the way you want it.

Comment: @RGuggisberg `Windows 200` - children's edition ? :)

Comment: One question: "our domain have corporate pg" - are you administrator? If so, why don't you override pg for this machine? If not, how do you intend to write in HKLM?

Comment: Yes I'm an admin at our local site, but there are still locked out settings on computers that and admin password can't undo because of the policies.  So registry seem like a good choice.

Comment: @Endoro - LOL - Should have been Windows 2000 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file in the %temp% folder and remove it after using regedit.